# Alfresco Rest API Vs. Activiti Rest API

Tags: alfresco, activiti

While searching for alfresco rest API,
I found in alfresco website this link :
[activiti rest api](http://docs.alfresco.com/activiti/topics/restApi.html)

There's another Rest API in alfresco wiki, which is workflow rest API: 
[workflow rest api](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow_REST_API)

I want to know the difference between them and which one is better to use in alfresco?

Comment: What kind of thing are you trying to do? Is it working with Activiti workflows, or other parts of Alfresco?

Comment: I have files to be managed using alfresco.
and workflow implemented and I use alfresco workflow rest api 

but i found the activiti api and I'm confused about the difference between them

As I know, Alfresco uses Activiti as a workflow engine. Why the provided rest api is different and not providing the same functionality ?

Comment: If you want to manage files, why are you looking at Workflow REST APIs then?

Comment: first comment has been edited, kindly check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously alfresco was using JBPM as workflow engine,JBPM workflow engine is deprecated in recent release of alfresco.Currently alfresco is using activiti workflow engine.

Activiti rest api
This api are used for Activiti workflow engine

workflow rest api
This were used for JBPM workflow engine